MT-Bench evaluation of a model using pre generated model answers
I want to find MT-Bench score of an LLM (say EleutherAI/pythia-1b).I was able to run the command

python gen_model_answer.py --model-pat EleutherAI/pythia-1b --model-id pythia-1b

to generate answers and I could see the output in the json file "data/mt_bench/model_answer/pythia-1b.jsonl".
I have downloaded pre generated model answers using the command

python3 download_mt_bench_pregenerated.py

How to compare "pythia-1b" generated answer and any pre generated answer(say llama-13b) to calculate MT-Bench score for "pythia-1b" model ?
